# how to parse this xml by using python?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I try a lot of ways,but I still can't extract data from it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><cwbopendata xmlns="urn:cwb:gov:tw:cwbcommon:0.1">
 <identifier>CWB_ANNUAL_DATA_20161017134902</identifier>
 <sender>weather@cwb.gov.tw</sender>
 <sent>2016-10-17 13:51+08:00</sent>
 <status>Actual</status>
 <msgType>Issue</msgType>
 <dataid>CWB_B0024-002</dataid>
 <scope>Public</scope>
 <dataset>
  <location>
   <locationName>BANQIAO,板橋</locationName>
   <stationId>466880</stationId>
   <weatherElement> 
    <elementName>逐時觀測</elementName>
    <time>
     <obsTime>2015-10-17 01:00</obsTime>
     <weatherElement>
      <elementName>測站氣壓</elementName>
      <elementValue>
       <value>1012.9</value>
      </elementValue>
     </weatherElement>
     <weatherElement>
      <elementName>溫度</elementName>
      <elementValue>
       <value>23.2</value>
      </elementValue>
     </weatherElement>
     <weatherElement>
      <elementName>相對濕度</elementName>
      <elementValue>
       <value>68</value>
      </elementValue>
     </weatherElement>
     <weatherElement>
      <elementName>風速</elementName>
      <elementValue>
       <value>3.9</value>
      </elementValue>
     </weatherElement>
     <weatherElement>
      <elementName>風向</elementName>
      <elementValue>
       <value>東北東,ENE</value>
      </elementValue>
     </weatherElement>
     <weatherElement>
      <elementName>降水量</elementName>
      <elementValue>
       <value>0.0</value>
      </elementValue>
     </weatherElement>
    </time>
    <time>
     <obsTime>2015-10-17 02:00</obsTime>
     <weatherElement>
      <elementName>測站氣壓</elementName>
      <elementValue>
       <value>1012.7</value>
      </elementValue>
     </weatherElement>
     <weatherElement>
      <elementName>溫度</elementName>
      <elementValue>
       <value>22.9</value>
      </elementValue>
     </weatherElement>
     <weatherElement>
      <elementName>相對濕度</elementName>
      <elementValue>
       <value>69</value>
      </elementValue>
     </weatherElement>
     <weatherElement>
      <elementName>風速</elementName>
      <elementValue>
       <value>3.3</value>
      </elementValue>
     </weatherElement>
     <weatherElement>
      <elementName>風向</elementName>
      <elementValue>
       <value>東北東,ENE</value>
      </elementValue>
     </weatherElement>
     <weatherElement>
      <elementName>降水量</elementName>
      <elementValue>
       <value>0.0</value>
      </elementValue>
     </weatherElement>
    </time>
    <time>
     <obsTime>2015-10-17 03:00</obsTime>
     <weatherElement>
      <elementName>測站氣壓</elementName>
      <elementValue>
       <value>1012.5</value>
      </elementValue>
     </weatherElement>
     <weatherElement>
      <elementName>溫度</elementName>
      <elementValue>
       <value>22.8</value>
      </elementValue>
     </weatherElement>
     <weatherElement>
      <elementName>相對濕度</elementName>
      <elementValue>
       <value>70</value>
      </elementValue>
     </weatherElement>
     <weatherElement>
      <elementName>風速</elementName>
      <elementValue>
       <value>3.7</value>
      </elementValue>
     </weatherElement>
     <weatherElement>
      <elementName>風向</elementName>
      <elementValue>
       <value>東北東,ENE</value>
      </elementValue>
     </weatherElement>
     <weatherElement>
      <elementName>降水量</elementName>
      <elementValue>
       <value>0.0</value>
      </elementValue>
     </weatherElement>
    </time>
    <time>
     <obsTime>2015-10-17 04:00</obsTime>
     <weatherElement>
      <elementName>測站氣壓</elementName>
      <elementValue>
       <value>1012.4</value>
      </elementValue>
     </weatherElement>
     <weatherElement>
      <elementName>溫度</elementName>
      <elementValue>
       <value>22.7</value>
      </elementValue>
     </weatherElement>
     <weatherElement>
      <elementName>相對濕度</elementName>
      <elementValue>
       <value>70</value>
      </elementValue>
     </weatherElement>
     <weatherElement>
      <elementName>風速</elementName>
      <elementValue>
       <value>3.1</value>
      </elementValue>
     </weatherElement>
     <weatherElement>
      <elementName>風向</elementName>
      <elementValue>
       <value>東北東,ENE</value>
      </elementValue>
     </weatherElement>
     <weatherElement>
      <elementName>降水量</elementName>
      <elementValue>
       <value>0.0</value>
      </elementValue>
     </weatherElement>
    </time>
    <time>
     <obsTime>2015-10-17 05:00</obsTime>
     <weatherElement>
      <elementName>測站氣壓</elementName>
      <elementValue>
       <value>1012.6</value>
      </elementValue>
     </weatherElement>
     <weatherElement>
      <elementName>溫度</elementName>
      <elementValue>
       <value>22.6</value>
      </elementValue>
     </weatherElement>
     <weatherElement>
      <elementName>相對濕度</elementName>
      <elementValue>
       <value>71</value>
      </elementValue>
     </weatherElement>
     <weatherElement>
      <elementName>風速</elementName>
      <elementValue>
       <value>2.2</value>
      </elementValue>
     </weatherElement>
     <weatherElement>
      <elementName>風向</elementName>
      <elementValue>
       <value>東北東,ENE</value>
      </elementValue>
     </weatherElement>
     <weatherElement>
      <elementName>降水量</elementName>
      <elementValue>
       <value>0.0</value>
      </elementValue>
     </weatherElement>
    </time>
    <time>
```

This was my code tried to extract data from it.

```
from lxml import objectify
path=r'C:\Users\champion\Desktop\data_science_race\weather\C-B0024-002.xml'
parsed=objectify.parse(open(path,'rb'))
root=parsed.getroot()
```

This part successfully extracted data from location and stationId.

```
data=[]
for elt in root.dataset.location:
    el_data={}
    skip_fields=['{urn:cwb:gov:tw:cwbcommon:0.1}weatherElement']
    for child in elt.getchildren():
        if child.tag in skip_fields:
            continue
        el_data[child.tag]=child.text
    data.append(el_data)
```

This part the obsTime can be extracted,but elmentName and elementValue can't be extracted it.

```
data=[]
for elt in root.dataset.location.weatherElement.time:
    el_data={}
    skip_field=['{urn:cwb:gov:tw:cwbcommon:0.1}time']
    for child in elt.getchildren():
        if child.tag in skip_field:
            continue
            el_data[child.tag]=child.text
        for descendent in child.getchildren():
            el_data[descendent.tag]=descendent.text
            for next_descendent in descendent.getchildren():
                el_data[next_descendent.tag]=next_descendent.text
    data.append(el_data)
```

Comment: There is a line with invalid close tag: `<value>1012.7<xx/value>`

Comment: I think it is my wrong,I already corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using [pyxb](http://pyxb.sourceforge.net/) for this type of task.

What you want to do is:

- Generate an xsd schema file from your XML (using Visual Studio or [a free online tool](http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html))
- Generate binding classes using pyxb (see the [30 second example](http://pyxb.sourceforge.net/index.html#thirty-second-example) in the docs). For an xsd file, the command is:`python pyxbgen cwbopendata.xsd -m cwbopendata`
- Use the [CreateFromDocument](http://pyxb.sourceforge.net/userref_usebind.html?highlight=createfromdocument) method to use the binding classes you generated

The resulting code is clean. As an example, the sample below prints the timestamps of your weather observations:

```html
import cwbopendata
import pyxb

data = cwbopendata.CreateFromDocument(open('cwb_data_example.xml').read())

for t in data.dataset.location.weatherElement.time:
    print(t.obsTime)
```